# Using traefik to route ssl to different servers on different dockers

Tags: docker, ssl, redirect, reverse-proxy, traefik

I am a noob to this, but after reading some good guides I got the following problem...

I have a homeserver set up on Ubuntu with docker running containers for different applications; plex, minecraft, portainer and traefik. I have successfully set up traefik with reverse proxy, https, ssl routing with lets encrypt and duckdns.org.

Since yesterday I have set up a RaspberryPi with hass.io on it for my home automation stuff. To get hass.io to connect to my Alexa account I need it to be https and since I already use traefik to certificate my connection to my server... I think I would be able to use it for this too..

But I cannot get it to work. How do I set traefik up so that it also can handle a server outside the docker on my server?`

From my docker-compose.yaml

```
 #Portainer - WebUI for Containers
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    hostname: portainer
    container_name: portainer
    restart: always
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
#    ports:
#      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/portainer/data:/data
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
    environment:
      - TZ=${TZ}
    networks:
      - traefik_proxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=portainer"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:portainer.${DOMAINNAME}"
#      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}; PathPrefixStrip: /portainer"
      - "traefik.port=9000"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds=315360000"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.contentTypeNosniff=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLHost=${DOMAINNAME}"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSPreload=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.frameDeny=true"

# Traefik reverse proxy
  traefik:
    hostname: traefik
    image: traefik:v1.7.18
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    domainname: ${DOMAINNAME}
    networks:
      - default
      - traefik_proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DUCKDNS_TOKEN=${DUCKDNS_TOKEN}
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.${DOMAINNAME}"
#      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}; PathPrefixStrip: /traefik"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds=315360000"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.contentTypeNosniff=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLHost=${DOMAINNAME}"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSPreload=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.frameDeny=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic.users=${HTTP_USERNAME}:${HTTP_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/traefik:/etc/traefik
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared

#traefik networks block, to set up reverse proxy
networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external:
      name: traefik_proxy
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

and my traefik.toml

```
#debug = true

logLevel = "ERROR" #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
InsecureSkipVerify = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

# WEB interface of Traefik - it will show web page with overview of frontend an$
[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
  address = ":8080"

# Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[file]
  watch = true
  filename = "/etc/traefik/rules.toml"

# Let's encrypt configuration
[acme]
email = "john.doe@notreal.com" #any email id will work
storage="/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging=true
onDemand = false #create certificate when container is created
[acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "duckdns"
  delayBeforeCheck = 300
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "notmine.duckdns.org"
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "*.notmine.duckdns.org"

# Connection to docker host system (docker.sock)
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "notmine.duckdns.org"
watch = true
# This will hide all docker containers that don't have explicitly
# set label to "enable"
exposedbydefault = false
```

The above is the working code, I just can't figure out how to make adjustments that's not breaking it all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was tricky, noob as I said, but it was posible to solve by adding another domain to the rules.toml and by that create a frontend wich pointed to a backend at another server. I used this guide to solve the problem: docs.traefik.io/v1.5/configuration/backends/file

So I had to add my "non docker server" to the traefik.toml as a new domain that needs a certificate

```
# Domain for my server on the Raspberry
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "eklandaresidenset.duckdns.org"
```

I also had to edit my acme.json file with the key... it sould do it by itself when you restart trefik, but I never got that to happen so I edited it myself and just copied the keys I already had in the file. :-)

Then I set up my rules.toml that I already had referenced in my traefik.toml but not created, so I did that and added this:

```
# Putting non-docker apps behind traefik proxy.
[backends]
  [backends.backend-anotherserver]
    [backends.backend-anotherserver.servers.anotherserver]
        url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyy" #the other servers local IP and port
        weight = 1

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend-anotherserver]
    backend = "backend-anotherserver"
     passHostHeader = true
     passTLSCert = true
    [frontends.frontend-anotherserver.routes.domain]
        rule = "Host:anotherserver.duckdns.org"  #created another server dns-subdirectory at duckdns.org pointing to the same IP as before... just to get another header!
     [frontends.frontend-anotherserver.headers]
       SSLRedirect = true
       SSLHost = "anotherserver.duckdns.org"
       STSSeconds = 315360000
       STSIncludeSubdomains = true
       STSPreload = true
       forceSTSHeader = true
       frameDeny = true
       browserXSSFilter = true
```

Problem solved!